# PIVOT operator not working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2. I am trying to convert one row to column to get result in desired format.

Table name : `GenderYearWise`

```
Year    Gender  Total
---------------------
2005    Female   374
2005    Male    1579
2006    Female   853
2006    Male    4769
```

I want to get result in following format :

```
Gender  2005    2006
----------------------
Female   374     853
Male    1579    4769
```

I am trying to get required format using following query :

```
Select 
    Gender, 2005, 2006
From 
    GenderYearWise
PIVOT
    (sum(total)
     for year IN ([2005], [2006])
) AS PitvotTable
```

But above query is returning these results :

```
Gender  (No column name)    (No column name)
--------------------------------------------
Female  2005                2006
Male    2005                2006
```

Can anyone please help me and identify the issue in my query?

Comment: Escape column name 2005 and 2006 to [2005], [2006].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SELECT statement add escape `[` and `]` for the column names 2005 and 2006, like `[2005], [2006]` will solve the issue.

Sample execution with the given data:

```
DECLARE @GenderYearWise TABLE ([Year] INT, Gender VARCHAR (100), Total INT);

INSERT INTO @GenderYearWise ([Year], Gender, Total) VALUES 
(2005, 'Female'  , 374),
(2005, 'Male'    ,1579),
(2006, 'Female'  , 853),
(2006, 'Male'    ,4769);

Select 
    Gender, [2005], [2006]
From 
    @GenderYearWise
PIVOT
    (SUM(total)
     FOR [Year] IN ([2005], [2006])
) AS PitvotTable
```

Result:

```
Gender  2005    2006
Female  374     853
Male    1579    4769
```

Also escape column name for the reserved keyword `Year`.

Comment: great, it works for me. but why we need to escape it?

Comment: Here `Gender` is the known column name from the table. But `2005` and `2006` are derived from the PIVOT. So in the select if didn't escape the column with `[]` it will consider as string. So it is showing the 2005 and 2006 are the data values.

Answer (score -2):

its working fine in my system

select  gender,[2005],[2006] from
genderyearwise t pivot( sum(total) for year in ([2005],[2006])) as pvt